# How do I record sound and send it to a server from a web application?

Tags: java, flash, web-applications, audio

I'm developing a web application.  It will allow people to link written phrases with spoken phrases.  In order for this application to be useful, random users must be able to record their own voices and send the sounds to the server.  If I just have an "upload wav" form, no one will use it.  **If I have a "record" button that streams or packages up audio to the server, people will use it.**

I'd be happy to use Flash to do this.
I'd be happy to use Java to do this.
I'd be *willing* to use .NET to do this ;)
I could use an external service API if there is one available.
The format of the audio is not important as long as I could replay it on other web pages.

How do I put a record button on my website?

Comment: There was a similar question I answered today : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651796/recording-audio-via-the-web-for-an-intranet-solution

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're reinventing [Forvo.com](http://www.forvo.com) ;-)
AFAIR, they use Flash to record.

Answer (score 1):

Flash has the ability to record sounds.

You don't need a flash media server because you don't need to "stream" audio to the server. The server side of your site can be written in PHP, .Net, or whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

One problem that may come up with using Flash: [NellyMoser Codec](http://nellymoser.codec.googlepages.com/learnmore).

Sounds like there are some tools that can do the conversion (though I'm not sure of the legality), and obviously some sites have gotten this sort of functionality working, but it's something to be aware of.