# How to get audio file from mic in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, speech-recognition, audio-recording

Using Google Apps Script I would like to ask user for audio input through a microphone, and then save the resulting file to google drive (preferably in flac format). I can then send the file to Google Cloud Speech API and get the text.

What are the approaches I can take to get the audio file from mic?

Comment: What did you tried? Do you already know how to create a UI?

Comment: I can make an HTML side bar, so presumably I could try to run a recorder interface that way. However, the sidebar limits significantly what can work in there and it doesn't work well with mobile. Perhaps there is an external app or service I can connect to? I am very new to Apps script. In Android Java I would use SpeechRecognizer which has all that built in, but I don't think that works on apps script or JavaScript, and they want you to use the cloud speech service, which doesn't have built-in recording interface.

Comment: Don't know if this is helpful, but I would suggest taking a look at webRTC. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK Google Apps Script doesn't include a service that helps to get the audio from a mic but you could use an external API or with JavaScript / HTML5 by creating a UI by using the [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/).

Related

- [Can I use javascript to record voice on a web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15082689/1595451)

Comment: Thank you. I think to work around this, I will just redo the project as an Android App, and interact with Sheets through the API.