# How to create Audio Recording WebApp?

Tags: php, javascript, html, audio, recording

I have to create a webapp to record a user's voice when a user visits my webpage and gives my webapp the permission to record his/her voice.

Can Anyone give me some idea which technology or API should I use to create such an App.

Can this be done using HTML, Javascript or PHP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it by flash or by launching applet

> Can this be done using HTML, Javascript or PHP ?

No

Comment: They're getting there though: http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html

Answer (score 0):

From stackoverflow

[Recording Audio via the Web for an Intranet Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651796/recording-audio-via-the-web-for-an-intranet-solution)

From web

http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_do_i_capture_an_internet_audio_stream.html

http://emoney.al.ru/capture-streaming-video-and-audio/

http://www.totalrecorder.com/